# How does one guarantee that the Lithium Ion Battery hasn't sat on a shelf for a long time?

Tags: battery, battery-life, windows-mobile, lithium-ion

Lithium Ion batteries being the [milk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lithium-ion_battery#Shelf_life) of batteries that they are; I was wondering if there is any way of obtaining a guaranteed fresh carton of power with an expiration date so one can tell if they are being ripped off or not?

I'd like a new battery for my ASUS626, but I'd like to make sure that I'm getting what I'm paying for!

Comment: Buying breakfast cereal or potato chips must be a real nightmare for you (items packed by weight, not volume). Why not speak to ASUS or the battery manufacturer about it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most manufacturers will print the production date onto their batteries, so just check that.

Of course, an unscrupulous manufacturer (or seller) could falsify the sticker, so the only real protection is an honest seller, plus a good warranty (e.g. "at least x mAh per charge for the first 300 charges"), plus a seller who actually stands by their warranty :-).

Answer (score 0):

After buying several dead and almost dead batteries, my neighbor has started taking a battery tester with her to the store.  She buys the battery, opens it right then and checks it, so it's easy to replace if it isn't any good.

Comment: Won't really help with this problem: The voltage will be fine, but the charge will not last as long with an aged LiIon. You can only test that with a full charge-discharge cycle, which usually takes several hours.

Comment: Of course testing for dead batteries is better than nothing, but you could just do that by putting it into your laptop.

Comment: Ah, I understand the question better now -- the battery IS rechargable, so dead or not isn't really the question.  The only advantage then to checking in the store is it saves a drive and prooves that what you are returning is the battery you just bought.